# installing a theme

Tags: theme

I am trying to install theme porto in vain. Here is where I am getting a problem on the instructions. Active SW Extensions, open command line in folder root of magento and run commands, `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

what is active SW extension?

I opened the command line and initiated `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, however, it prompts me to rerun `magento compile command`.

I have run the compile command, `./magento setup:di:compile`
compilation starts and stops after repositories code generating line. Please help.

Comment: me too.. have same problem..
smone give info plz..

Answer (score 1):

When adding a theme into a Magento 2 install, you don't have run any command line to see if the theme is being seen by Magento. If the code is added to the correct path `app/design/frontend/{{vender_namespace}}/{{theme_name}}` then the `registration.php` file will automatically be seen and show up in the admin as a theme to select.

You should be able to navigate to the theme selection in the admin `store-> settings-> config-> general-> design-> design theme`

If you don't see your theme there, it's installed in the wrong location in the file structure or the `registration.php` is not correct.

Once you set the theme in the admin, then run the `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command from the root of your Magento install and the files will compile into the `pub/static` folder.

Running the `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command is only needed when installing extensions, which the theme might have packaged in some way. But I have found that most theme developers are still finding out how to package themes, with no clear pattern as of yet. And the only time you need to run the `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` is when you are getting ready to shift from developer mode to production. The message in the command line that tells you to run that seems to be a hold over from the beta days that never got removed. While developing, I have never needed to use it.